# Specific Keymapping JS

Tags: javascript, html, onkeydown

I'm not super familiar with DOM events and such. Currently, what I'd like to do is click on the first object, which is a HTML  link with the class name "test", when the user presses 1 on the keyboard and or keypad as well. I'd be using the keydown event since it seems more supported then keypress. How would I go as to doing this?

Comment: Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keydown

Comment: A bit confused as char and key are unimplemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery for example:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 49 // press key 1 on keyboard
        || event.keyCode == 97) // press key 1 on keypad
        location.href = $('a.test').attr('href');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrVdv/3/)

Comment: Thank you! How do I handle the first and second "test" links though? It works like a charm.

Comment: You can use selector in jquery like `a.test:eq(0)` for the first one and `a.test:eq(1)` for the 2nd one. Or `a.test:lt(2)` for the first 2.